# La nuit des millénaires

Tags: expressions

Dans *Manon de Sources*, on trouve cette description poétique :

[image: citation du livre]

> quelque glacier raboteux qui s'était fondu dans la nuit des millénaires.

Mais « la nuit des millénaires » m'est un peu obscur. J'imagine que ce veut dire « il y a des millénaires » mais je n'en suis pas certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour moi ça évoque l'expression *la nuit des temps* ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/la_nuit_des_temps), [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/nuit/55230)), donc le passé très lointain, indéterminé, voire le « début » du temps, un peu comme les *temps [immémoriaux](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/imm%C3%A9moriaux)*...

Comment: Tu as gagné de 7 secondes :-)

Comment: J'ai failli « perdre » parce que j'achoppais sur un truc...

Comment: Waouh, très belle expression alors ! Je te le donne pour tes 7 secondes ...

Comment: On trouve aussi *la nuit des siècles*.

Answer (score 2):

La formule est construite à l'image de **dans la nuit des temps** et garde le même sens.

[Expressio](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/la-nuit-des-temps) :

> *Époque très éloignée dans le passé ; temps immémoriaux ; les temps reculés ; Les temps reculés, si anciens que leur souvenir s’est effacé dans la mémoire des hommes.*